# Only host computer is able to use printer

Tags: windows, networking, printing, network-printer

I have a printer connected to a PC. The printer works fine on that single computer. The printer is also shared on LAN. Everything was working properly and each computer on LAN was able to use the printer. However, yesterday the printer showed status as "offline" on every computer and I am only able to use the printer from the computer, which has a direct connection to the printer with a USB cable.

I've tried every single thing that I came about while searching for the solution:

1) I checked Network advanced sharing settings, they are configured properly;

2) I checked the printer settings - the printer is set to be shared and **is not set to work offline**;

3) I restarted the "Print spooler" service;

4) Restarted the printer and the hosting PC (duh).

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - For some unknown reason, firewall started blocking connections to this computer, so turning the firewall off solved the issue.

**EDIT:** I would love to know as why this is the case and what allowance rule should solve this.